# Does it make sense to have READ_BIT in source access mask?

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

Memory barriers are supposed to prevent read-after-write and write-after-write hazards. After a read operation, the data is unchanged so there should be no need to make it available.

But the spec and validation layers do allow `READ_BIT` flags in `srcAccessMask`. Some implicit dependencies are defined as:

```
VkSubpassDependency implicitDependency = {
    .srcSubpass = lastSubpass; // Last subpass attachment is used in
    .dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT;
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT |
        VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT |
        VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT |
        VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT |
        VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    .dstAccessMask = 0;
    .dependencyFlags = 0;
};
```

I've also seen this after mipmap generation in the Khronos Vulkan samples:

```
// After the loop, all mip layers are in TRANSFER_SRC layout, so transition all to SHADER_READ
vkb::insert_image_memory_barrier(
    blit_command,
    texture.image,
    VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT, // srcAccessMask
    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, // dstAccessMask
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
    {VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, texture.mip_levels, 0, 1});
```

Is the `READ_BIT` redundant in such cases, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `READ_BIT` is indeed redundant. Quoting spec author from [VulkanDocs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/131):

> So we've now completely resolved that READ in srcAccessMask is
> completely a no-op. If we hadn't been previously implying that you
> needed it, then we'd probably make it invalid. Instead we're just
> going to leave it as a no-op, and hopefully add a warning to the
> validation layers that it's a no-op. This should be clear in the spec
> in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1389) to clarify the implicit dependencies in spec, and it's planned to add a warning in the best-practices validation layers.